# Add string of arraylist in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

I need to add arraylist of items in linq.Below is my sample code.

```
string[] _str = ("1.21,2.02,3.14,4.951,5.156").ToString().Split(',');
double Sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < _str.Length; i++)
{
  if (_str[i].ToString() != ",")
     Sum = Sum + Convert.ToDouble(_str[i]);
}
```

The above code i have done in for loop to get the sum of all items in the array list. I need to convert the same operation in linq.Please anyone help me solve this since i'm new to linq.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in LINQ?

Comment: The first line is so redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] _str =  {"1.21","2.02","3.14","4.951","5.156"};
double Sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < _str.Length; i++)
{
    double.TryParse(_str[i],out val)
}
```

But if you are doing this for sake of learning linq

```
string[] _str = {"1.21","2.02","3.14","4.951","5.156"};
_str.Sum(x => 
    {  
       double val ; 
       if(double.TryParse(x, out val)){
         return val;
       }
       return 0.0;
    });
```

If you are sure that the string will always contain valid numeric strings. Then you can just use double.Parse(x).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734.aspx) method:

```
string[] _str = "1.21,2.02,3.14,4.951,5.156".Split(',');
var result = _str.Sum(e => Double.Parse(e));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,if suppose a value that is coming from DB is like this 1.21,2.02,3.14,4.951,5.156, . Is there any code change will occur.

Comment: @Neon Sorry, I don't understand you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
string[] _str = "1.21,2.02,3.14,4.951,5.156".Split(',');
double Sum = _str.Sum(x=>Convert.ToDouble(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
var _str = _str = ("1.21,2.02,3.14,4.951,5.156").ToString().Split(',');
var _sum = Array.ConvertAll<String, Double>(_str, Double.Parse).Sum();
```

Another one liner, with method chaining example...

```
var _sum = "1.21,2.02,3.14,4.951,5.156".Split(',').Sum(x => Double.Parse(x));
```